# Command for running integration test in flavored app

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I do not know what will be the command for running integration test in flavored app.
I have used `flutter test --flavor app1 integration_test/test.dart` but it can't load the asset image provided in the login page. And thats why it shows `Some tests failed` in the console. Can anyone suggest a solution?

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
 integration_test:
```

Comment: Can you provide more info to this like the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I have edited my pubspec.yaml